# Colors not displayed from Scala REPL output in Windows

Tags: windows, scala

Oddly enough, I typed `val f = 1` using repl, and it showed below

```
scala> val f = 1

[33mval[0m [36mf[0m: [35mInt[0m = [31m1[0m
```

Is there a configuration problem, or something else?

PS: I use Windows 7 64-bit, Scala 3.1

Comment: The `[33m` and similar tokens are "color tokens" (I don't know the right name), they should be used by your shell to colour the output. The issue lies in your shell, not with Scala or the Scala REPL. How are you running it?

Comment: Those are ANSI color codes. Note that this is probably a JLine problem rather than anything truly Scala-specific.

Comment: I opened Scala REPL through CMD：
C:\Windows\System32>scala Welcome to Scala 3.1.0 (11.0.2, Java Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM). Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help. 
scala> var f = 1 
[33mvar[0m [36mf[0m: [35mInt[0m = [31m1[0m scala> 
How to solve this problem, please？@Gaël J @Seth Tisue